# Ubuntu 22.04 desktop icons disappeared

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and my desktop icons suddenly disappeared. Maybe after some faulty software update. My desktop is now completely empty. Even though when I go the directory `Home/Desktop` all the desktop content is still there.

How do I get my desktop icons back?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` extension

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng`

see https://devicetests.com/restore-desktop-icons-ubuntu